# What's the safest way to pipe an email to a script via procmail?

Tags: scripting, email, procmail

I have a simple procmailrc recipe that hands mail off to a script:

```
LOGFILE=/home/foouser/procmail-log
VERBOSE=yes
MAILDIR=/var/spool/mail/foouser
DEFAULT=/var/spool/mail/foouser
SHELL=/bin/sh
DELIVERED=yes
COMSAT=no

:0
| `/home/foouser/scripts/footool/footool.sh`
```

The script itself is pretty resilient and reasonably safe.  My concern is that the procmail recipe itself might not sanitize correctly and in the process of piping it over, an email that contains, say, `; rm -rf /` could wreak havoc.  Should I use double-quotes?

### MORE INFORMATION

Based on some feedback [here](http://pm-doc.sourceforge.net/doc/#avoid_extra_shell_layer_and_check_command_for_shellmetas), it sounds like I might want to temporarily disable shell metas and use double-quotes.

So that would perhaps change the recommended code implementation to:

```
LOGFILE=/home/foouser/procmail-log
VERBOSE=yes
MAILDIR=/var/spool/mail/foouser
DEFAULT=/var/spool/mail/foouser
SHELL=/bin/sh
DELIVERED=yes
COMSAT=no
savedMetas  = $SHELLMETAS
SHELLMETAS    # Kill variable

:0
| "/home/foouser/scripts/footool/footool.sh"
SHELLMETAS  = $savedMetas
```

Does that look better?

Comment: http://pm-doc.sourceforge.net/doc/#avoid_extra_shell_layer_and_check_command_for_shellmetas

Comment: regular use is without any quotes or backticks after pipe.

Comment: @grebneke Forgive my ignorance but I'm not sure I fully understand the article.  I added a new example.  Can you please review?

Comment: @MikeB - Forgive me, I might have misread your post. Will post answer below in a second.

Comment: It is extremely unclear what you are trying to accomplish.  What is the output of `footool.sh`?  If it outputs shell commands that Procmail should interpret (which your first syntax means) then it should escape them properly before printing them.  On the other hand, your attempt at a "fixed" solution does nothing of the sort.  Please describe your problem in more detail. Until then, nominating for closing as unclear what you are asking.

Comment: To understand the meaning of DELIVERED and COMSAT, the best reference I found was http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man5/procmailrc.5.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This invocation is incorrect, unless you're somehow trying to run a command whose name is the *output* of `footools.sh`:

```
:0
| `/home/foouser/scripts/footool/footool.sh`
```

This is normal syntax:

```
:0
| /home/foouser/scripts/footool/footools.sh
```

`procmail` will execute `footools.sh` and pass the email to the script on `stdin`.

No need for `$SHELLMETAS` or special escaping. `$SHELLMETAS` is for unusual cases where you need to send special characters as *arguments* to your script, but don't want those arguments interpreted by a shell. You can safely ignore it for a simple use case like above.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response.  I'm getting confused though... in one of the prior links you referenced above, it mentioned adding `savedMetas  = $SHELLMETAS` followed by 
`SHELLMETAS    # Kill variable` and then `SHELLMETAS  = $savedMetas` at the bottom.  That's not needed?  It's "safe" with a straight-up pipe?

Comment: @MikeB - Yes it's safe. I misunderstood your initial question. No need to touch `$SHELLMETAS` except for the (unusual) case where your script needs special *arguments* containing any of the SHELLMETA-characters. It will not influence the data you send on *stdin*, it concerns special script *arguments* only.

Comment: @grebneke Does this need locking similar to sending the email content to a file? Or is each email's shell invocation in its own session so no locking is required? Thanks.

Comment: @Vishnu No locking needed at this level. The executed script itself might need locks to manage handling of a shared resource like a file, but that is outside the scope of this question. Basically the script should be designed to handle multiple parallel independent executions of itself.